# Qual a serventia de blocos aninhados em Java?

Tags: java

Vi algo escrito semelhante ao código abaixo. Esse segundo bloco no método **metodo** tem alguma utilidade? Tem como ser usado de alguma forma?

Rodei este código e ele compilou e apareceu apenas a mensagem *Primeiro print.*, não apresentando *Segundo print.*.

Já vi algo parecido com o try...catch...finally, mas este não é o mesmo caso.

Se puder ser usado de alguma forma, alguém me escreve um exemplo prático?

```
public class BlocoAninhado {

    public static void main(String[] argumentos) {
        BlocoAninhado.metodo();
    }

    public static void metodo() {
        System.out.println("Primeiro print.");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Segundo print.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O bloco exemplo que você deu é um [*Instance Initializer*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6763550/1000282) com propósito diferente de um simples bloco de escopo. Sempre que você encontrar estes blocos soltos dentro do corpo de uma classe, se trata disso e não dos blocos de escopo de variáveis.

Um irmão do *Instance Initializer* é o *Static Initializer*:

```
public class BlocoAninhado {

    public static void main(String[] argumentos) {
        BlocoAninhado.metodo();
    }

    public static void metodo() {
        System.out.println("Segundo print.");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("Primeiro print.");
    }
}
```

Este deve executar, e o bloco do seu exemplo não executa por que não é criada uma instância dessa classe. O *Static Initializer* executa porque não está vinculado à instância, assim como qualquer método estático.

O outro caso de blocos soltos são os comuns que você encontra dentro das funções, estes são blocos de escopo. Um uso comum e útil deles é nos `case`s do comando `switch`:

```
switch(foo) {
  case BAR: {
    int x;
  }
  break;

  case BAZ: {
    char x; //usando o mesmo nome sem problemas.
  }
  break;
}
```

---

Para ilustração, isto faria o tipo de bloco que você está usando executar:

```
public class BlocoAninhado {

    public static void main(String[] argumentos) {
        (new BlocoAninhado()).metodo();
    }

    public static void metodo() {
        System.out.println("Segundo print.");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Primeiro print.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria se fosse uma classe sem `main`. Daí seria exatamente um `Instance Initializer`.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar ainda é um `Instance Initializer` o fato de ter um `main` não importa, o que acontece é que como não é criada uma instância de fato dessa classe, um `Instance Initializer` não é chamado, se fosse um `Static Initializer` seria.

Answer (score 3):

Os blocos do Java possuem várias aplicações

## Corpo de classes e métodos

Classe:

```java
class C { ... }
```

Método:

```java
void m() { ... }
```

Implementações *inline*:

```java
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { ... }
};
```

## Agrupar declarações em condicionais, laços e controle excepcional

Condicional:

```java
if (cond) { ... } else { ... }
switch (valor) { case 1: ...; break; default: ...}
```

Laços:

```java
while (cond) { ... }
do { ... } while (cond)
for (...) { ... }
```

Controle excepcional e de encerramento:

```java
try { ... } catch { ... } finally { ... }
```

## Blocos arbitrários

São colocados no meio do código e seguem o fluxo normal de execução, porém com um escopo próprio, o que significa que as variáveis declaradas deixarão de existir no seu fechamento.

```java
int a = 1;
{
    int b = a + 2; //b == 3
}
//b não existe mais
```

Isso provavelmente é permitido por uma questão de linguagem, isto é, um bloco pode substituir um comando válido na gramática do Java. Isso simplifica muito a implementação porque o compilador não precisa fazer uma verificação especial para permitir blocos apenas em comandos específicos.

## Labels

É possível usar o comando `break <label>` para interromper a execução de um bloco em específico.

Não consegui pensar em nenhuma aplicação prática, então vai um exemplo sem o menor sentido mesmo assim:

```java
int a = 1;
myLabel: {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        a++;
        if (a == 5) {
            break myLabel;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Não vai imprimir isso!");
}
System.out.println(a);
```

## Inicializadores de instância e de classe

De instância (executa antes do construtor):

```java
classe C {
    { ... }
}
```

Estático (executa quando a classe é carregada no primeiro uso:

```java
classe C {
    static { ... }
}
```

### A ordem de execução

Uma questão interessante sobre os blocos de inicialização é sobre a ordem em que eles são executados, considerando que há o construtor do objeto e inicializações de atributos.

Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```java
public class Initializations {
    static class X {
        static int y(String str) { 
            System.out.println("y(" + str + ")");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    static class A {
        static { 
            System.out.println("static initializer A"); 
        }
    static int y = X.y("static A");
    int y2 = X.y("instance A");
        { 
            System.out.println("instance initializer A"); 
        }
        public A() {
            System.out.println("constructor A");
        }
    }
    static class B extends A {
        static int y = X.y("static B");
        int y2 = X.y("instance B");
        static { 
            System.out.println("static initializer B"); 
        }
        { 
            System.out.println("instance initializer B"); 
        }
        public B() {
            System.out.println("constructor B");
        }
        public void imprime() {
            System.out.println("imprime()");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("init main");
        new B().imprime();
        System.out.println("end main");
    }
}
```

Irei comentar o resultado produzido pelo código acima:

1. `init main`: o primeiro item é do método `main`, logo as subclasses não foram inicializadas.
2. `static initializer A`: ao executar `new B()` o Java executa primeiramente o inicializador estático da classe Pai.
3. `y(static A)`: em seguida, o atributo estático `y` da classe `A` foi inicialiada.
4. `y(static B)`: em seguida, o atributo estático `y` da classe `B` foi inicialiada.
5. `static initializer B`: agora, sim o inicializador estático de `B`.
6. `y(instance A)`: agora o atributo de instância `y2` da classe `A`.
7. `instance initializer A`: agora o inicializador de instância da classe `A`.
8. `constructor A`: e o construtor de `A`.
9. `y(instance B)`: agora o atributo de instância `y2` da classe `B`.
10. `instance initializer B`: e o inicializador de instância de `B`.
11. `constructor B`: terminando a sequência de inicialização, o Java executa o construtor de `B`.
12. `imprime()`: e o método de instância é chamado.
13. `end main`: finalmente o método `main` termina.

Com base nisso, podemos dizer que a ordem de execução é:

1. Variáveis e inicializadores estáticos, começando da classe pai e terminando na filha, e na ordem em que estão declaradas no corpo de cada classe da hierarquia.
2. Começando mais uma vez na classe pai e terminando na filha, são executados, nesta ordem, inicialização de variáveis de instância, inicializadores de instância e construtores.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é principalmente utilizado para declarar que uma variável pertence apenas aquele escopo. Por exemplo:

```
public class Teste{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Teste.imprime();
  }

  public static void imprime(){
    {
      int i = 0;
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    {
      int i = 2;
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Você conseguirá compilar com sucesso e terá como saída:

```
0
2
```

No entanto, se você inverter, por exemplo, a ordem das linhas no segundo bloco:

```
public class Teste{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Teste.imprime();
  }

  public static void imprime(){
    {
      int i = 0;
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    {
      System.out.println(i);
      int i = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Você receberá o seguinte, para este código, o seguinte erro de compilação:

```
Teste.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
                        System.out.println(i);
                                           ^
```

Ou seja, serve como uma forma bem primária de **encapsulamento**, restringindo o acesso **apenas** ao bloco que ela pertence.

Comment: No exemplo da pergunta o bloco aparece fora de qualquer  função, no escopo da classe.

Comment: Na verdade a linha a mais foi colocada pelo NetBeans @GuilhermeBernal. Muito bom Felipe, obrigado.

Comment: @GarouDan tem certeza que não é o caso da resposta que dei. São coisas bem diferentes.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, eu coloquei dentro do outro, porque, caso você tente executar o exemplo proposto, ele só executará o primeiro `print`.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Acontece que, a pergunta tem um tom leigo de alguém que viu algo e não sabe o que é. Você não respondeu sobre o código dado, e a descrição dada é vaga, porém o código é válido, você no final deu uma resposta baseada numa suposição que não deriva do código dado, o qual pode ser de fato o que o OP viu por aí.

Comment: @pepper_chico concordo que isso possa ter acontecido, mas, ainda assim, posso pressupor que o código que o OP viu estaria semelhante com a minha suposição (não estou dizendo que nem eu ou você estamos errados), mas o fato de não instanciar o objeto é o que mais me chama a atenção para não ser um `Instance Initializer` (além do fato de não ser usual, apesar de possível, instanciar a própria classe com um `main`), esse conjunto de características me levou a minha suposição, como a ausência de chaves levou você a supor que fosse um `Instance Initializer`.

Comment: Então, parece que é outro caso mesmo. vou dar uma olhada @pepper_chico.

Comment: @GarouDan à vontade =)