# O que é e como funciona um bloco static no Java?

Tags: java

Estudando Java me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
static {
    System.out.println("bloco estático inicializado");
}
```

Depois acabei por chamar o método `main` e o bloco foi executado. Como é que isso acontece? Sei que um método `static` não precisa da instância de um objeto para nos referirmos a ele, mas precisamos pelo menos os chamar pelo nome. Não entendi muito bem o por quê que o bloco é executado.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a serventia de blocos aninhados em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8531/qual-a-serventia-de-blocos-aninhados-em-java)

Comment: [Blocos estáticos, herança e construtores em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104512/blocos-est%C3%A1ticos-heran%C3%A7a-e-construtores-em-java)

Comment: @diegofmpelas respostas parecem que é duplicata mesmo. Eu esperava que tivessem novidades não postadas antes.

Answer (score 1):

**Os blocos de inicialização** são executados quando uma instância é criada ou quando a classe é carregada pela JVM. Eles não possuem retorno, nome e parâmetros.

Os **blocos de inicialização estático** são executados só quando a classe é carregada pela primeira vez. Blocos de inicialização de instância executam sempre que uma nova instância é criada.

Regras, retiradas no site [Java Naveia](http://kamilladoria.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/blocos-de-inicializacao.html):

> - blocos de inicialização de instância são executados na ordem em que aparecem;
> - blocos de inicialização estáticos só rodam uma vez, quando a classe é carregada pela primeira vez na JVM;
> - blocos de inicialização de instância rodam toda vez que uma nova instância é criada e depois da chamada do método `super()` dentro do
>     construtor.
>
> Se houver várias classes na árvore de herança com vários blocos
>   estáticos, todos eles serão executados antes dos blocos de instância.

Referência: [Java naveia](http://kamilladoria.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/blocos-de-inicializacao.html)

Comment: O link da referência está quebrado.

Comment: @diegofm, arrumado.

Answer (score 1):

Um **bloco estático** é executado somente uma vez, imediatamente após a primeira referencia a `class`, isto é, no carregamento da memória.

Como o **bloco de estático** é executado no carregamento da classe, consequentemente será executado antes da chamada ao construtor da classe.
Dentro de um bloco de código estático poderemos acessar somente atributos e métodos estáticos.

Exemplo

```
static {
  XABLAU = 0;   // Bloco executado uma única vez quando a classe é carregada
}
```

Detalhes

- [What is a static block and how should I use it?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=249930)